# Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : variable lengths differ (found for 'factor(DAF)')

Tags: r

I'm working with a regression model `(MWT1Best= 428 - 7.69*Diabetes - 72.1*AtrialFib - 130*DAF)` where I am trying to quickly see the value of the model if I replaced 1 or 0 in variables `Diabetes` and `AtrialFib`. I'm having a lot of trouble understanding why I get this error when I use `prediction()`:

```
list("Diabetes" = prediction(r123, at = list(Diabetes = c(0, 1))),
     "AtrialFib" = prediction(r123, at = list(AtrialFib = c(0, 1))),
     "Diabetes*AtrialFib" = prediction(r123, 
                at = list(Diabetes = c(0, 1), AtrialFib = c(0, 1))))

Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'factor(DAF)')
```

All of my variables "Diabetes", "AtrialFib" and "DAF" have the same length and don't have any missing values:

```
> length(COPD$Diabetes)
[1] 101
> length(DAF)
[1] 101
> length(COPD$AtrialFib)
[1] 101
> sum(is.na(COPD$Diabetes))
[1] 0
> sum(is.na(COPD$DAF))
[1] 0
> sum(is.na(COPD$AtrialFib))
[1] 0
```

Here is more information about my dataset:

```
> str(COPD)
'data.frame':   101 obs. of  24 variables:
 $ X           : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ ID          : int  58 57 62 145 136 84 93 27 114 152 ...
 $ AGE         : int  77 79 80 56 65 67 67 83 72 75 ...
 $ PackHistory : num  60 50 11 60 68 26 50 90 50 6 ...
 $ COPDSEVERITY: Factor w/ 4 levels "MILD","MODERATE",..: 3 2 2 4 3 2 3 3 2 3 ...
 $ MWT1        : int  120 165 201 210 204 216 214 214 231 226 ...
 $ MWT2        : int  120 176 180 210 210 180 237 237 237 240 ...
 $ MWT1Best    : int  120 176 201 210 210 216 237 237 237 240 ...
 $ FEV1        : num  1.21 1.09 1.52 0.47 1.07 1.09 0.69 0.68 2.13 1.06 ...
 $ FEV1PRED    : num  36 56 68 14 42 50 35 32 63 46 ...
 $ FVC         : num  2.4 1.64 2.3 1.14 2.91 1.99 1.31 2.23 4.38 2.06 ...
 $ FVCPRED     : int  98 65 86 27 98 60 48 77 80 75 ...
 $ CAT         : int  25 12 22 28 32 29 29 22 25 31 ...
 $ HAD         : num  8 21 18 26 18 21 30 2 6 20 ...
 $ SGRQ        : num  69.5 44.2 44.1 62 75.6 ...
 $ AGEquartiles: int  4 4 4 1 1 2 2 4 3 3 ...
 $ copd        : int  3 2 2 4 3 2 3 3 2 3 ...
 $ gender      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ smoking     : int  2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ Diabetes    : int  1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ muscular    : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ hypertension: int  0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ AtrialFib   : int  1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ IHD         : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

I created DAF by multiplying `Diabetes` and `AtrialFib`, and also more info on `r123`

```
> DAF<-COPD$Diabetes*COPD$AtrialFib
> str(DAF)
 int [1:101] 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 ...
> r123<-lm(MWT1Best~factor(Diabetes)+factor(AtrialFib)+factor(DAF), data=COPD)
> summary(r123) 

Call:
lm(formula = MWT1Best ~ factor(Diabetes) + factor(AtrialFib) + 
    factor(DAF), data = COPD)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-218.15  -51.88   18.70   51.85  270.86 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          428.14      10.39  41.200  < 2e-16 ***
factor(Diabetes)1     -7.69      28.02  -0.274  0.78436    
factor(AtrialFib)1   -72.05      29.21  -2.467  0.01541 *  
factor(DAF)1        -130.11      47.70  -2.727  0.00759 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 86.32 on 96 degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.3635,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3437 
F-statistic: 18.28 on 3 and 96 DF,  p-value: 1.841e-09
```

Comment: I am not sure what package contains the `prediction` function.  But the base `predict()` function uses a dataframe and not a list.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The function comes from a package with the same name ```prediction``` and it's supposed to extract predicted values via ```predict``` from a model object and return a data frame. I tried to remove the list like you said but unfortunately got a similar error:
```> prediction(r123, data=find_data(r123, parent.frame(COPD$Diabetes)), at = list(Diabetes=c(0,1)))
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'factor(DAF)')```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears since one of your predictor values is a function of your two other predictor values, it looks like your use of the `prediction` function with the DAF predictor is incorrect.

Since I don't have your model in order to test, this is more of a brute force solution using base R's predict function. Here we are generating all of the possible combinations of your 2 predictor variables and your derived variable (only 4 combinations in this case).

```
#Devise the new test matrix
predictdf<-expand.grid(Diabetes=c(0,1), AtrialFib = c(0,1))
predictdf$DAF <- predictdf$Diabetes * predictdf$AtrialFib

#convert from integers to factors (to match the model)
predictdf<-apply(predictdf, 2, factor)
#preform the prediction
predict(r123, data.frame(predictdf))
```

To simplify the problem, allow R to calculate the interaction term directly within the linear regression formula:

```
lm(MWT1Best~factor(Diabetes)*factor(AtrialFib), data=COPD)
```

Replace the + with * and the model will take all of the interactions into account.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I did your first method and unfortunately got an error again ```Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or an array``` The function ```predict``` doesn't seem to accept matrices. The second method works, I'm just wondering if there's an easier way for me to replace 1 and 0 in the predictor variables without having to calculate them by hand?

Comment: Oh, actually the second method works perfectly! I basically removed DAF like you said and it works great: ```r123<-lm(MWT1Best~factor(Diabetes)+factor(AtrialFib)+factor(Diabetes)*factor(AtrialFib), data=COPD)``` and then I just entered it into the original code ```list("Diabetes" = prediction(r123, at = list(Diabetes = c(0, 1))),
     "AtrialFib" = prediction(r123, at = list(AtrialFib = c(0, 1))),
     "Diabetes*AtrialFib" = prediction(r123, at = list(Diabetes = c(0, 1), AtrialFib = c(0, 1))))``` I won't post the output since it's too long but there's no more error. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The first answer works now too! I had to google how to accept an answer, didn't realise it could be done. I've accepted, thanks again!